# How to get route name from path in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible in twig to get the route name from a path given (not the current one).

I know that to get the current route, it is like this :

```
{% set current_path = app.request.get('_route') %}
```

but this is not what I am looking for. I want to give another path than the current one.

---

Here is come code of what I want to do

With javascript (Mootools), I add an event on some buttons.

```
element.addEvent("click", function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();

                        AjaxFormValideEtEnregistrement(element.get('href'));
                    });

function AjaxFormValideEtEnregistrement(href) { 

//href is a path and I want to get the route..

if i create a route filter I cannot do this :

{{ href|route }}
```

I guess it is not possible .
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible out of the box. You are supposed to create your own Twig extension and develop a function, eg `router_generate` which will:

1. Match a route by provided path
2. Return the name of the matched route

Also, if you could explain better what's the use case for such functionality maybe we could assist you with some other, possibly better way of achieving your goal.

Comment: the problem is that I cannot applied a twig filter that I created on a javascript variable.

Comment: Then you need a controller which will respond asynchronously to JS requests to return a route name for the requested path.